# PowerApps: Inserting range of numbers into SQL

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I'm trying to insert a range of serial numbers into the SQL Server table.

I'm using the following code but it inserts only one record:

```
Patch('[dbo].[SerialNos]', Defaults('[dbo].[SerialNos]'),
{Equipment: varEquipNo, 
    SerialNumber: "123456", 
             Loc: varStorLoc
})
```

How can I modify it to use a range of serial numbers (ex. From SerialNo - To SerialNo) :

[image: Range of Serial Numbers Insertion]

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to generate a range of numbers in PowerApps currently, but you can use something like the example below:

```
ForAll(
    FirstN(
        [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
        Value(txtSerialEnd.Text) - Value(txtSerialStart.Text) + 1),
    Patch(
        '[dbo].[SerialNos]',
        Defaults('[dbo].[SerialNos]'),
        {
            Equipment: varEquipNo,
            SerialNumber: Value(txtSerialStart.Text) + Value,
            Loc: varStorLoc
        }))
```

This adds a limit on the size of the range of numbers, but you can add more numbers to the first parameter of `FirstN` if you want to support a wider range of values.